# Removing span on click after successful ajax-call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the (parent) span of a hyperlink when the hyperlink (.remove_resort) is clicked (after successful ajax call).

Although the ajax call is successful, the span is not removed at the end. What is wrong here?

Keep in mind : there are several similar spans with class remove_resort...

```
<span><a title="remove resort from skiregion - are you sure?" id="xrr43" class="pointer remove_resort"> - remove resort </a></span>
$('.remove_resort').on('click', function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault();    
 pos = $(this).attr("id");
 rem_res(pos);
});    
function rem_res(pos)
{    
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/snowreport/request/remove.php',
     data: {
         res_id: pos
      },
     success: function(msg) {
     $(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
     $(this).html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);
     $(this).parent().remove().delay(2000);
                });
            }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Your `this` is wrong. Use arrow functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `id` to get the element instead of `this`

```
success: function(msg) {
     $(“#”+pos).fadeOut(800, function() {
        $(this).html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);
        $(this).parent().remove().delay(2000);
     });
}
```

Comment: probably the chaining of events could be more efficient ?

Comment: @mark you can have a try,due to I am not sure if it will work when you invoke `delay(2000)`

Comment: you are right. remove is not an animation and should be delayed with settimeout. Thanx!